# Mouseover event for bar plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, mouseover

I was trying to make an interactive plot using matplotlib where I would get the index of the bar plot clicked. That way I could access some details stored in an array using the index and have it printed. I have a sample of the code below that can be used for line graphs.

```
    if isinstance(event.artist, Line2D):
        thisline = event.artist
        xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
        ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
        ind = event.ind
        print('onpick1 line:', np.column_stack([xdata[ind], ydata[ind]]))
```

However, I was unable to get any such ind/index for a bar plot. Is there any work around?

Comment: You can use [this example](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/bar.html) from [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bars are individual patches. You can get the index of the patch from the returned list.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.random.rand(len(x))
info = list("ABDCEFGHIJ")

bars = plt.bar(x,y, picker=True)

def on_pick(evt):
    ind = bars.index(evt.artist)
    print(ind, info[ind])

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event", on_pick)


plt.show()
```